# Is it possible to create a bucket that doesn't use sub-folder buckets?

Tags: buckets

I have an item that will contain a large number of subitems as direct children, which I would like to give bucketing treatment to.

Unfortunately these items don't have a reasonable way to be grouped in subfolders.

I've created a custom rule in Item Bucket Settings:

```
Example Rule
where the item bucket is based on the [Examples] template
  and where the new bucketable item is basedon the [Example] template
create the new folder structure based on the name of the new bucketable item with [0] levels
```

Choosing `0` levels defaults the bucket path to use the creation date of the item in the default `yyyy/MM/dd/HH/mm` format.

**Is there a way to bucket these items without the intermediate folders?**

I'd prefer that they be accessed at `http://example.com/examples/example-name` rather than `http://example.com/examples/ ... path here ... /example-name`, and I'd rather not need to introduce a `*` item just to correct the paths.

Comment: Is there any reason for creating a bucket in the first place then? Buckets were introduced to avoid the performance issues when an item has more than 100 direct children. This is not only an issue in the UI, but also when executing queueries.

Comment: @KasperGadensgaard, mostly for the UI enhancements. This item will have more than 100 children, and accessing those items will still happen through the queryable API.

Comment: @zzzBov you can still get the UI enhancements without the parent item being a bucket, if you mean the search UI part. If that is what you want can you update your question with that? We don't have to limit it to solving the Item Bucket folder option then

Comment: @RichardSeal, I'm not going to limit my question just because it'd be convenient.

Comment: @RichardSeal, That all said, if you'd like to ask/answer that subset by all means go ahead. It could be useful to have.

Comment: @zzzzBov sorry - I just had an idea about how you can reach your goal - added the answer below. It just doesn't match the exact question you asked.

Comment: @RichardSeal, I had an alternative thought that might work in a super hacky sort of way. I'm going to give it a try and then either comment about it if it doesn't work, or write it up if it does.

Comment: Unfortunately my alternative thought didn't work. The thought was to make the grandparent a bucket with a custom path of `Examples`, and then create *another* item named `Examples` in the grandparent. Unfortunately, this either led to duplicate items that always resolved to the bucket or the items directly within the non-bucket `Examples` item, without the nice UI hiding that I was hoping to have.

Comment: as a very worst case scenario I can use a custom bucket path of `_`, which would make it `http://example.com/examples/_/example-name`, which isn't ideal but is tolerable.

Comment: Have you investigated using the `ItemResolving.FindBestMatch` setting that was added in 8.1 Update 2? Admittedly, this has caused some very incorrect behavior with wildcards in our solution, so we disabled it. But it sounds like it may fit your use case (depending on how well it actually works with the version of Sitecore you're on). I did not post this as an answer, because again, we disabled it and have not fully investigated the setting. You can find a description of each mode for the setting in `Sitecore.config` past 8.1 Update 2.

Comment: @JustinLaster, I didn't spend too long attempting to fix the "grandfathered bucket" solution because it produced a number of other issues (children of the "grandfather" were buckets, and then *all* the items got reorganized and that was a lot of fun).

Comment: I my humble opinion you are setting yourself up for a world of pain. There are several really good reasons why the number of child items should be limited, particularly performance and caching. Let buckets work like they should and look into URL manipulation/item resolving to achieve the nice URLs.

Comment: @Eldblom, I'd love for buckets to "work like they should", just without the additional intermediate folders. After significant exploration into this it appears that item buckets weren't designed to be that flexible, and that I'll need to do exactly as you said: URL manipulation/item resolution.

Answer (score 10):

This answer does not *exactly* match your question, but I believe it matches your requirements based on the comments you have made.

If you want the Item Bucket search features on the parent item but do not want the child items added into sub folders you can easily add those features to the parent item.

Make sure that you can view `Standard Fields` and find the `Editors` field of the parent item. Then you can add the `Search` editor to the list and move it to the top so it becomes the default:

[image]

If you have multiple items based off the same template you can also do this on the Standard Values of the item.

[image]

Then you have all the search features and can just add child items as normal.

#### Edit:

To make the sub items hidden then you can set that on the standard values of the templates of the items you add to the parent:

[image]

This items will only be visible if the `Hidden Items` checkbox on the View ribbon is ticked:

[image]

Comment: This would work so long as I never expand the parent or ever look at the items it contains.

Comment: @zzzzBov I have included an edit that enables you to do that.

Comment: Oh good point with the hidden items. It is a bit strange, but the whole situation is a bit strange.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, there is. I wrote a bog post about it:

https://www.skillcore.net/sitecore/sitecore-item-buckets-custom-folders-structure

In shoortcut you need to create action extending `RuleAction<T> where T : BucketingRuleContext` and set `ruleContext.ResolvedPath` to whatever you want.

Here is the example of action which adds author user name to the folder structure:

```c#
public class AuthorAndCreateDateBasedPath<T> : CreateDateBasedPath<T> where T : BucketingRuleContext
{
  public override void Apply(T ruleContext)
  {
    base.Apply(ruleContext);
    if (Sitecore.Context.Data != null && Sitecore.Context.Data.User != null)
    {
      ruleContext.ResolvedPath = 
        Sitecore.Context.Data.User.LocalName + "/" + ruleContext.ResolvedPath;
    }
  }
}
```

You can create your action in similar way.

Then we create new Action under `/sitecore/system/Settings/Rules/Definitions/Elements/Bucketing` item and set Text and Title fields like that:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for updating your post, however I think you're misunderstanding my question. I'm not asking about how to create a custom bucket path [as I've already written about it myself](https://www.geekhive.com/buzz/post/2015/04/how-to-create-custom-item-bucket-rules-in-sitecore-cms/). I'm asking how to make the custom path **empty**, which is getting overridden by Sitecore's default pathing behavior.

Comment: You're welcome. I think Iunderstood your question. What I suggest is to create a custom action which will set the path to empty string or whatever you need. From what I know you cannot do this with Sitecore out of the box actions. That's why I showed all the necessary steps. You just need to change one line which sets path to "author + basedResolvedPath" (and naming). And that should be it.

Comment: I appreciate the work you've put into this answer, and to be absolutely certain, I wrote a custom rule that sets the `ruleContext.ResolvedPath` to empty string. Testing gives me the same `yyyy/MM/dd/HH/mm` result as I described in the question. To be sure I had everything configured properly, I also tested it with a value of `"foo"`, which worked as expected, putting all items in a `foo` bucket.

Comment: I've run into an interesting situation. Out of curiosity I updated `ruleContext.ResolvedPath` to `"/"` and bucketing now "works" with the items directly under the bucket, however creating items triggers a save dialog and the UI no longer hides subitems with the "there are hidden items..." message.

Comment: @zzzzBov that is because the way an item bucket hides the content is because the Bucket Folders are marked as hidden on the std values. Same way as my answer

Comment: @RichardSeal, are you referring to the Appearance>Hidden field on `/sitecore/templates/System/Item Buckets/Bucket/__Standard Values`? I'm not seeing that checked.

Comment: you are right, it must be doing something special with that template. I can't see anything that marks it as a "bucket folder". Either way, its the folders that hide the content rather than the items.

Comment: @RichardSeal, yea, I've discovered that all it takes to display the "there are hidden items..." message  is to include one of the `Bucket` items as a child, regardless of if there are any items *within* the bucket item or not. I attempted extending the bucket template just to see if the behavior was inherited, and it doesn't appear to be either.

Comment: @RichardSeal would I be right in understanding that creating this custom action and a rule that uses it would result in a bucketed parent item where the path of the child items does not change. i.e the path of the items is the same as if they were below a non-bucketed parent? e.g /Products/ProductName instead of Products/2017/01/09/ProductName. Also will this rule apply correctly to an Parent Item that already exists with child items in it?